# Testcontainers: FileNotFoundException: .testcontainers.properties

Tags: docker, micronaut, testcontainers, testcontainers-junit5

I am getting issues with running integration tests (using `JUnit5`) of my `micronaut` app on my `Windows 10 Pro` machine. My tests depend on two containers, that I defined using [Testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) java library: `RabbitMQ` and `MS SQL server`. The `Docker` version is `v19.03.13`.

Upon running integration test, I am getting the following exception:

```
[WARN ][DESKTOP-PBCHP60] [testcontainers.utility.TestcontainersConfiguration] – Attempted to read Testcontainers configuration file at file:/$HOME.testcontainers.properties but the file was not found. Exception message: FileNotFoundException: $HOME\.testcontainers.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Though, I am not getting this exception when running the test from `macOS` machine. My assumption is that it is `Windows` specific.

Can anyone tell me how to fix it? Should I create the required file myself? Or maybe there is a way how to skip the step of reading this file during running IT?

Comment: Could you describe how you run your tests? Are you running inside an IDE, or command line, and if so which shell?

Comment: @BurtBeckwith, thanks for your response. Both options fails. For command line it is powersell.

Comment: The message you posted is just a warning, not an error. It should not prevent testcontainers from launching the docker images. Are there any error messages? They should start with `[ERROR]`.